# QByteArray conversion from text

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have a textedit where I key in the hex number, and then this text to be converted into QByteArray.

This is my code:

```
QByteArray parsedValue = QByteArray::fromHex(expectedPacketStr.toUtf8());
qDebug() << parsedValue;
```

when I set it to **001102**,
then console log reports `"\x00\x11\x02"` which is what I expected.

But if i set it to **001122**,
the console logs reports `"\x00\x11\""` which is missing the x22 byte.

I really cannot understand what's going on. Anybody have any clue why is this so???

Comment: Note that hex value 22 is the ASCII value for the quote character.  The third byte isn’t missing, it’s just displayed as \”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x22 is the character " in ascii, so it's just qDebug() that is interpreting it, and nothing is missing inside QByteArray.

To convince you, you can always display the array one by one:

```
for (auto b : parsedValue)
    qDebug() << (int)b;
```